# SQL query logic to capture the period end date

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have table that captures users payment plan, created date, next created date which I have created using the sql lead function  as follows
I want to create last column that is previous period plan A type date.

The requirement is to capture the previous next created date for plan type A and when the consecutive plan is not equal to type A is should populate the previous next created date of the plan type A.

I don’t know how to do this in sql,
And I’m using Amazon redshift

Tried using self join, however it resulted in duplicate records
[image]

Also this is my first time posting on stack overflow please let me know if any additional information is required.
Thank you all, really appreciate.

Comment: Please read : [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952) ***and*** [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is this a picture of the input data? Please also provide the query you have tried so far and the output you want given this input data.

Comment: Yes it’s the input data, output required same table with additional column i.e column E as the previous next created date for plan type A